# Syntax error, unexpected '>' when putting ERB in image_tag ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation in my app where I need to render a set of images with the element ID in each image's ID tag.  It looks like this:

```
<% things.each do |thing| %>
  <%= image_tag "ballerino.png", id: "voteDownAnimation<%= thing.id %>", class: "hidden", style: "position: fixed; z-index: 100; height: 70vh" %>
  <%= image_tag "fist-left.png", id: "voteUpAnimationLeft<%= thing.id %>", class: "hidden", style: "position: fixed; z-index: 100; width: 50%" %>
  <%= image_tag "fist-right.png", id: "voteUpAnimationRight<%= thing.id %>", class: "hidden", style: "position: fixed; z-index: 100; width: 50%" %>
<% end %>
```

If I remove the `<%= thing.id %>` from the id tags it renders fine, but with it it yields this error:

syntax error, unexpected '>'

```
... z-index: 100; height: 70vh" %>
...                              ^
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this?  I've been staring at it for hours, but can't see anything syntactically wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code with below, you have to use string [#interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html) 
 :-

```
<%= image_tag "ballerino.png", id: "voteDownAnimation#{thing.id}", class: "hidden", style: "position: fixed; z-index: 100; height: 70vh" %>
```

Above you are using ruby tag under ruby tag means :-

```
<%=  <%= %> %>
```

which is syntactically wrong in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

For string interpolation you should use `#{}` instead of `<%= %>`

Change

```
<%= image_tag "ballerino.png", id: "voteDownAnimation<%= thing.id %>", class: "hidden", style: "position: fixed; z-index: 100; height: 70vh" %>
```

to

```
<%= image_tag "ballerino.png", id: "voteDownAnimation#{thing.id}", class: "hidden", style: "position: fixed; z-index: 100; height: 70vh" %>
```